# BASH | Adding elements in all files of a specific directory bash

Tags: bash, for-loop

Assuming that I have in the folder :

> MyFolder

the following files :

> File1.txt File2.txt File3.txt File9.txt Bob.txt

I want to apply the following algorithm, but I don't know how to do it in Bash (actually the loop For is what I don't manage to do) :

```
 For (each file of MyFolder directory)
      add "<end>" at the end of the current text file
 EndFor
```

What is the proper syntax in bash for that ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can make it:

```
for file in /your/dir/*
do
    echo "<end>" >> "$file"
done
```

In case you have some dirs inside, you may get the error `bash: XX: Is a directory`. To avoid seeing them, you can add `2>/dev/null` to the end of the `echo` command:

```
echo "<end>" >> "$file" 2>/dev/null
```

Or even better ([thanks Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375021/bash-adding-elements-in-all-files-of-a-specific-directory-bash/18375071#comment26981999_18375071)), check if they are files:

```
[ -f "$file" ] && echo "<end>" >> "$file"
```

Which is a short way of doing an if-condition:

```
if [ -f "$file" ]; then
   echo "<end>" >> "$file"
fi
```

Comment: You could also use `if [ -f "$file" ]`

Comment: Don't forget to quote the variable, in case the filename contains whitespce.

Comment: I don't understand the last version pointed out by @Barmar. Could you explain it please ? Does it contain "IF" or not ?

Comment: `X && Y` is the same as `if X; then Y; fi` because of the way boolean short-cutting works.

Comment: The expression `[ -f "$file" ]` evaluates to `0` or `1` (true or false) depending on if `"$file"` is the name of an actual file, or something else (e.g. a directory). You could use an `if` to check this, but fedorqui has used a sneaky trick, that `&&` is a short circuited logical AND: it will run left hand side, and **only if it is true**, bother running the right hand side (and effectively returns a true or false based on both parts, but that final value is ignored here).

Comment: I see. Thank  you very much ALL. It is very clear to me now. I'm most grateful. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

one way would be something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
folder="myfolder"
for i in `find $folder/ -type f`
do
    echo $i
    echo "<end>" >> "$i"
done
```

Comment: Good one! You could add `-maxdepth 1` (before -type f) not to include files in subfolders.

Comment: @svante No it is not good. It will fail if the filenames have spaces in them (or other special characters), or it too many files are found. See here for more discussion: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: @user000001 you are so right. Will you please inspect my proposed alternative solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375021/bash-adding-elements-in-all-files-of-a-specific-directory-bash/18377293#18377293.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `find` one liner :

```
find /your/dir/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sh -c 'echo "<end>" >> {}' \;
```

Where `-maxdepth 1` keeps from including files in subfolders,
`-type f` is for finding files only and `-exec` fires the echo command for each found item.